How to setup Isolated LXD Container with Internet Access Only
I have multiple Ubuntu LXD containers for various clients running on an Ubuntu LXD host. For the LXD containers to do software installs from the internet I have attached a bridge. Required ports from the LXD containers are exposed to public IP ports using the LXD proxy device. This is the current setup.
Going forward

I want to restrict LXD containers from connecting to each other.


may be a separate bridge for each container, which would solve it. Is there any better solution.


I also want to restrict LXD containers from accessing LXD hosts ports while maintaining an internet connection for software installations in containers.


A. I have no idea.

Basically, I need an isolated LXD container with Internet access Only. How can I achieve this? Please help.
Thank you

vlans can be used usually and firewall as usually?

@djdomi by vlans do you mean macvlan?

You can create separate Network for each of your Containers. Docs.
you don't necessarily need separate bridge carriers just different network for each container
lxc network create <network_name> --type=physical parent=br0
lxc network attach <network_name> <instance_name>


Thank you for your response. By br0 do you mean an lxc bridge?

On reading further into types there are three types, macvlan,  sriov and physical. Especially on macvlan there is a Note saying If you are using a macvlan network, communication between the LXD host and the instances is not possible. Both the host and the instances can talk to the gateway, but they cannot communicate directly. https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/stable-5.0/reference/network_macvlan/ But I don't see this in physical. Does this means in physical type, host and container can communicate directly?

Also on using type physical can't create different network for each container. For second network it will say Error: Parent interface "eth0" in use by another network

br0 is bridge pointing to eth0. it got noting to with lxc it's created manually using netplan config.
there are more than tree types. https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/howto/network_create/
communication directly is not possible in macvlan but they can both communicate with gateway. btw do u need containers to access host directly ?
i didn't know that about physical type. i think you can create sub interfaces and use them as parents with diffrent vlan for each but i am not sure.

No, I don't want container to access host directly.
